# How to make input (picture) visible after reaching some score?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code (some kind of clicker game) that should show you next button (image) after reaching some score (in this example 10) and this button (image) gives you more points then previous one etc. My problem is that I cant make my second button (image) to appear.

```js
var score_count = 0
var pic1 = document.getElementsByClassName('btn1');
var pic2 = document.getElementsByClassName('btn2');

function addToScore(amount) {
  score_count = score_count + amount;
  document.getElementById('score_count').innerHTML = score_count;

}

if (score_count >= 10) {
  pic2.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
.score {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.btns:active {
  transform: scale(0.98);
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 22px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.btn2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<p class="score">Score: <span id="score_count">0</span></p>

<input id="pic1" class="btn btns" type="Image" name="Image1" src="imgs/pic1.jpg" height="256px" width="256px" onclick="addToScore(1)">

<input id="pic2" class="btn2 btns" type="Image" name="Image2" src="imgs/pic2.jpg" height="256px" width="256px" onclick="addToScore(5)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `if` condition needs to be inside the function & i assume you want to hide the first button after that.so thats what i did & i changed `document.getElementsByClassName` with `document.getElementById`.because with `document.getElementsByClassName` you will get an `array` of `objects` in that case you have pass an `index` for.eg

`var pic1 = document.getElementsByClassName('pic1')[0];`

```js
var score_count = 0
var pic1 = document.getElementById('pic1');
var pic2 = document.getElementById('pic2');

function addToScore(amount) {
    score_count = score_count + amount;
    document.getElementById('score_count').innerHTML = score_count;
    
    if (score_count >=10) {
    pic2.style.visibility = 'visible';
    pic1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

}
```

```css
.score{
    font-size: 40px;
}
.btns:active{
    transform: scale(0.98);
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 22px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.btn2{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Score</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <p class="score">Score: <span id="score_count">0</span></p>

    <input id="pic1" class="btn btns" type="Image" name="Image1" src="imgs/pic1.jpg" height="256px" width="256px" onclick="addToScore(1)">

    <input id="pic2" class="btn2 btns" type="Image" name="Image2" src="imgs/pic2.jpg" height="256px" width="256px" onclick="addToScore(5)">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Damn I was doing the same thing but it didnt work and even when I copied ur code it didnt work but when I tried it in other IDE it worked. I guess It's problem with sublime text :/

Answer (score 1):

Your selector indicates all class i.e. `btn2`.
Either you must use `getElementById` method or select the first element by using `pic2[0]`.
In addition, your if condition should be inside of `addToScore` function.

```js
var score_count = 0
var pic1 = document.getElementsByClassName('btn1');
var pic2 = document.getElementsByClassName('btn2');

function addToScore(amount) {
    score_count = score_count + amount;
    document.getElementById('score_count').innerHTML = score_count;
        if (score_count >=10) {
      pic2[0].style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

```css
.score{
    font-size: 40px;
}
.btns:active{
    transform: scale(0.98);
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 22px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.btn2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p class="score">Score: <span id="score_count">0</span></p>

    <input id="pic1" class="btns" type="Image" name="Image1" src="imgs/pic1.jpg" height="256px" width="256px" onclick="addToScore(1)">

    <input id="pic2" class="btn2 btns" type="Image" name="Image2" src="imgs/pic2.jpg" height="256px" width="256px" onclick="addToScore(5)">
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the evaluation of the conditional occurs only when the script is first loaded.
One way to solve it is to move this block:

```
if (score_count >=10) {
    pic2.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

inside the `addToScore` function, that way it's going to evaluate it every time the score updates.

I believe you're just starting out with JS, otherwise I'll tell you a better solution would be to work with events.
Inside your `addToScore` function, you can trigger an event when `score_count` is greater or equal to 10, and then declare the event listener, learning it this way grants you a better understanding of what you can achieve with javascript.